# Node.js Unhandled Error

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, child-process, unhandled-exception

I am having an issue with my Node.js script in the Cloud9 online IDE. I am using the child_process module to run a python script, pass an input with stdin, and receive an output with stdout. I keep receiving an error. Here is the part of my code in question

**Node.js**

```
try {
    var spawn = require ("child_process").spawn;
    var pyProcess = spawn ("python2", ["pythonScript.py"]);
    pyProcess.stdin.write ("Test");
    pyProcess.stdout.on ("data", function (data) {
        console.log (data);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log (e);
}
```

**Python**

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write (sys.stdin.read())
sys.stdout.flush()
```

**Error**

```
<Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f>
events.js:141
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:557:26)
```

When I remove the line

```
pyProcess.stdin.write ("Test");
```

the error goes away. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Handle the error event?

Comment: How do i do that? The error is in events.js line 141. That's not my file.

Comment: The library you are using _may_ throw an error that you need to be preared to handle. To do that, use a [try catch](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/errors/what-is-try-catch/).

Comment: Ok i've tried that now. Now it prints out <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f> right before printing the same error.